Facing an issue in play-console: You won't be able to release app updates (35 days away)
I am migrating my whole native android project to flutter and the development is on the final stage. But I am facing an issue on my legacy application:

This is because of the legacy's minimum sdk version is 33 and playstore requires minimum sdk version 34. However, I can't update my older app, because it uses many older libraries incompatible with sdk version 34 and there is no time left to fix it.
If I am unable to complete within the time period, what was the next step I could follow to update my new flutter app (which meets whole policies of play console)?

after this period you will be able to push updates for this app, which will target 34 at least. (app stays in Play Store and is visible/searchable as usual, but probably "ranked" lower by GP search/suggestion engines)
so your old code would need target update (and probably some support changes in code) and your new project would need to have same package name and signed by same keys (assuming it have already proper target set)
looks like for some time you won't be able to push updates (e.g. quick hot bug-fixes) - old code would need much work (besides fix) and you are close to have "new version", on which you are focusing
